# Deserializing in VB Without Failing When the File Does Not Exist

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, serialization, xml-serialization

I've nicked some code from msdn to write and read to an xml file to persist my data, but I need a little help with it. I have a dynamic array called darr. As I understand it, I use this code to store it in an xml file:

```
    Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter("C:\temp\test.xml")
    Dim x As New XmlSerializer(darr.GetType) 
    x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, darr)
    objStreamWriter.Close()
```

And this to read it:

```
    Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader("C:\temp\test.xml")
    darr = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
    objStreamReader.Close()
```

The thing is, I want the app to read from the file on startup, which means the second block gets called first and if the file doesn't exit yet, it throws an exception. (The first block automatically creates the file if not found.) So two questions:

1. Is there a way to have the app create the file automatically the first time it runs?
2. Since the file will be empty... will the code work? If not, is there a workaround? (Okay that's three questions!)

Comment: You can easily try these things for yourself.

Comment: So, you have no understanding of file IO? Because the answer is pretty obvious in the `System.IO.File` class.

Comment: I'm just learning the language, trying to teach myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Here's a pointer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/dd492171.aspx. Also, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx, where you'll easily guess that the answer is [`System.IO.File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 If Not File.Exists("C:\temp\test.xml") Then 
        ' Create the file. 
          Dim file As System.IO.FileStream
          file = System.IO.File.Create("C:\temp\test.xml")
    Else
           Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter("C:\temp\test.xml")
           Dim x As New XmlSerializer(darr.GetType) 
           x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, darr)
           objStreamWriter.Close()
 End If
```